# ssh: "Agent admitted failure to sign using the key"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, password, remote-access

I'm trying to set up password-less login with ssh on Ubuntu Server,
but I keep getting:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key
```

and prompt for password.

I have generated new rsa keys. Before the system reboot it worked just fine.

All the links lead me to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/201786), but nothing works. SSH Agent is still not running.

How to fix that? Maybe the files need specific permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem involves two machines. WHich was re-booted?  ssh-add will only add the key on the client.  If the key isn't accepted, there isn't a client error and a server error will only show up if the -v option is used when ssh is invoked on the client, to request the connection.

I suppose its possible too that Ubuntu the package has, for some unknown reason, altered the error message shown.  It isn't an error issued by openSSH-server, as it is used in Debian (or anywhere else I've seen it, e.g. RHEL, CentOS, Knoppix, others).

Answer (score 81):

just run:

`ssh-add` + path to key

on the client (your pc)

Comment: I like `ssh-copy-id user@host.server.tld`.

Comment: Isn't it lovely when you spend an hour banging your head against the wall & the answer turns out to be this simple

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: worked magically! but can anyone explain what happened under the hood?

Comment: This works but I don't know _why_ it works because I didn't think I was using ssh-agent.

Comment: Why it need to be done? Because Debug says it already offers the correct id `debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/charles/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 4):

My problem was resolved by executing `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0`, as explained in [ssh Agent admitted failure to sign using the key on big endian machines](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/201786) on the Ubuntu bug tracker.

Comment: That disables usage of the ssh-agent all together. – The problem is not in getting rid of it, but to use it! Btw: unsetting the variable has the same effect.

Comment: This is not a real solution because us disables ssh-agent. Check this instead:
https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign/

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Ubuntu Bugtracking](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/201786) you mentioned, this is a known bug in gnupg-agent it self. so upgrading to a new gnupg-agent version >2.0.14-1ubuntu1.7 solve the problem.

Comment: This [Github article](https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign/) mentions the same Ubuntu issue report and has some helpful suggestions including the same fix as @user46329: `ssh-add`.